# Rails undefined method 'job_app'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i want to create the view:
1. for normal user, to see it job app status:

```
def index 
    @users ||= current_user
    @job_apps = @users.job_app

end
```

It works perfectly on view.
2. Trouble (job_app method undefined) : create view for admins so they can see all candidates:

```
def empl
    @users = User.all.where(:user_type => 'candidate')
    @job_apps = @users.job_app.all
end
```

Note : without @job_apps i can see all the users as well.

Comment: You say you have "trouble" when attempting to create the view for admins. What, exactly, is that trouble? We can't give you an answer unless you tell us what's wrong. Post any error messages, console output and expected vs. actual behavior.

Comment: @MarsAtomic edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make a bit of an educated guess here: `job_app` is indeed a method of the `User` class, but what you're dealing with in your controller's `empl` method is not an instance of `User`, but rather, an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which is more or less an array of `User` objects. `User.job_app` works because `job_app` is a member of `User`, but not of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

To achieve what you want, you have to do some iterating through the elements of that array within the view associated with your `empl` method.

controller code:

```
def empl
    @users = User.all.where(:user_type => 'candidate')
end
```

view code:

```
<% @users.each do | user | %>
  <%= user.job_app %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @MarsAtomic this works, but what if i want to make something like accept or refuse method? I have to deal again with it, but i do not have idea how to write link_to to update the job_apps table

Comment: @andrey Write up what you want in a separate question and you'll get an answer. Try to keep your questions on Stack Overflow as atomic as possible so that when someone searches for something, they can find the exact answer to their question, no more, no less.